# Calculate Days between Dates and write to HTML (almost complete)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the days between dates and when I choose the 2 dates it doesn't show anthing in my heading. How can I implement this? This should be able to make calculations between dates many years apart to it has to consider February has 28 days etc...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">


<div class="row">
           <label>From System Date:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="initialDate">
                    <input type='text' name="initialDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $('#initialDate').datetimepicker({
                            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>To System Date:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='finalDate'>
                    <input type='text' name="finalDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#finalDate').datetimepicker({
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <script>
                function CalculateDayends() {
                   var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
                   var initialDate = $('#initialDate');
                   var finalDate = $('#finalDate');
                   return Math.round(Math.abs((initialDate.getTime() - finalDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
                }
            </script>
            <h4>DAYENDS to run: <b><script>document.write(CalculateDayends())</script></b></h4>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is showing because your vars initialDate and finalDate are just strings.

This getTime() function is always used in conjunction with a Date object.

Just use:

```
var diff =  Math.floor(( Date.parse(finalDate) - Date.parse(initialDate) ) / 86400000);
```

This will give you the days between your two dates picked.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53c63pc1/)

Comment: I mean. After I click insert 2 dates the function should be called again. How??

Comment: how can I make on change?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working fiddle so you can see how it's done. Please mark as the correct answer if this has helped :)